# Content-based advertising for a fully ajax application

Tags: ajax, ads

I've built a php/js application that relies completely on AJAX so none of the content is static. 
I'm trying to find a way to ad content-based advertising that uses the AJAX delivered content as keywords.

Google's Adsense doesn't really support AJAX and
I'm having a really difficult time finding another provider.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

making some assumptions here. 1.) you're using JSON.

send to the adwords a link to a "statically" rendered slim page of your to-be-updated content, let Google match that content with the ad, capute the ad, and return both the content and the ad via JSON to your page and insert them in the DOM accordingly?